# The voip service which don't care about ACD/ASR?

Tags: asterisk, voip, freeswitch

I need to know which  voip termination service(A-Z International Termination) doesn't care about ACD / ASR .

**ACD** (Average Call Duration) 
Means the average duration of the calls routed bya a VoIP provider. It is a quality parameter given by the VoIP providers..

**ASR** (Answer-Seizure Ratio)

The ratio of successfully connected calls to attempted calls (also called 'Call Completion Rate'). ASRs vary by routes. A typical ASR to Pakistan is lower than that of France. Reasons for this include the quality of the network and the fact that it's less likely that a call to Pakistan will encounter a device such as an answering machine.

For example : my dialer ( Aterisk/ FreeSwitch ) may call minimum of 50 calls per seconds . majority of them can be a missed call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many carriers have two routes: Conversational and Dialer.

The dialer routes are *intended* for higher CPS/CPM and are tolerant of much lower ACD/ASR. Check the individual carrier to see exactly what they allow.

Some that I'm familiar with:

- [Voxbeam](http://www.voxbeam.com/rates) -- they call it "Call Center"
- [Alcazar](http://www.alcazarnetworks.com/termination_dialer.php) - they call it "Dialer / short Duration"

Answer (score 0):

There are no services which not care about ASR. Even contract for diallers require ASR >10%.

Only contract which not care about ASR can be with per-call fee,including placed nto answered calls.

Reason is simple: there are some people who not do answered call at all, so pay nothing to company but use company resources.

Comment: which provider just having ASR >10% and without ACD

Answer (score 0):

All good VOIP Service providers do care about both ASR and ACD. The reason is resource utilization. If the callers make calls which do not get connected and/or quickly disconnected then the VOIP Service providers' resources, one example is ports, get blocked just for ringing the other end with no revenue, the system processor cycles are lost depriving other potential good revenue calls to go through. The billing seconds are very less in low ASR and low ACD calls so the providers want to charge a different (higher) rate for these type of calls to make up for the lost resource utilization.